# With Debian, how can I remove a directory that isn't empty?

Tags: debian

In Debian, I want to remove a subdirectory of my home directory. When I try to remove it (with `sudo`), I get a message saying the directory is not empty, but I cannot see any file inside the directory with `ls -l`.

How do I remove this directory?

Answer (score 8):

rm -rf /home/user/directory

Comment: Thanks for this help. it worked. Thanks to all of you for your quick response. :-)

Answer (score 3):

try `ls -a` to see if there's any hidden file.

You can remove recursively using `rm -r`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ls -a -l
```

To show hidden files, then remove them.

Or, to force the directory and everything inside it to be deleted, try:

```
rm -r directory
```

Answer (score -1):

Load up your terminal and type the following:

```
cd ~/

rm -rf ./my-directory
```

This should work assuming you have the correct permissions

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is a reason you are suggesting to connect via SSH?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were doing this on a remote machine. I've updated my answer accordingly.